# js if(!value > 0) on number input validation returning incorrectly

Tags: javascript

In this example:

```
<form name="someform" action="somepage.php" method="post">
    <input name="length" id="length" type="number" min="1" oninput="validate()"/>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

I want to disable the submit button for any length value that is not greater than 0. I have min="1" on the input, which works fine when the users rely on the up/down buttons to enter a value, but it does not stop them from entering a 0 with the keyboard. So I have added the following validation js function.

```
function validate() {
   var valid = true;
   length = document.getElementById("length").value;
   if(!length > 0) {
       valid = false;
   }    
   document.getElementById("submit").disabled = valid == false;
}
```

This function returns valid = true if you enter a 0 in the box and I don't understand why. If you have a number in the box and delete it so that the box is empty, it will return false, but 0 is always true here.

edit: You can enter a negative number, like -5 and that also returns true.

I have a jsbin example here: http://jsbin.com/qatekupuzu/edit?html,js,console,output

Any help in getting this working correctly would be appreciated.

Comment: also variable name - `length` is not ideal, should be value or something else

Comment: lyu, length is the label on that input in the live form because the value is the length of an item.

Comment: I think your comment's issue is you need `===` since in js `"" == 0` will return true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need fo any `if` just store the test inside the boolean `valid` directly. Like this:

```
function validate() {
   var length = document.getElementById("length").value; // get the value
   var valid = length > 0;                               // if length is > 0 then valid will be true, otherwise it will be false
   document.getElementById("submit").disabled = !valid;  // disable if only valid is false
}
```

Comment: This answer is perfect. I'll accept it as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't write `!length > 0`. Instead use `length != 0` or `length <= 0`

Answer (score 1):

Seems nobody has caught this, so I'll throw this answer in to shed some light on what is really going on here.

The reason your statement is behaving like this is because it isn't the statement you think it is. Let's inspect it and see.

`if(!length > 0)` is what you typed. This statement inside the `if` is actually two statements. `!length` gets evaluated first, then its value is compared with `> 0`.

`!length` evaluates to a boolean, which is only `true` iff the number is 0. Any other number evaluates to `false`. Then because the left operator of `>` is a boolean `> 0` is evaluated as `boolean > boolean`, which only evaluates to `true` iff the statement is `true > false`.

So the issue is not the statement returning incorrectly, you just aren't using the statement you want. What you intended to write is `if( !(length >0) ){ valid = false; }` or more concisely `if(length <=0) { valid = false; }`

EDIT: Another factor is at play here which fooled me based on the variable name `length`. Calling `typeof(length)` reveals that this variable is a `string` despite the `number` enforcement on the element. The above applies the same for type `string` with the modification that `!""` is the only string that evaluates to `true`.

I am unclear whether or not you are attempting to validate the length of this string being longer than 0 (i.e. not empty), or if you want to validate that the number the user entered is greater than 0. If the former is the case, then evaluating `length.length` is what you want. For the latter, you would need to parse this as an `int` first using `parseInt()`.

Comment: @AnonymousMan Yes, I added this to my answer because I realized that I didn't actually answer the question.

Comment: actually placing the ! outside the parens just caused errors for me.

Comment: Oh, I just realized that your `length` variable isn't actually a number, it's the value of the input field. Are you meaning to test the length? Then it should actually be `length.length`, or as someone suggested, the variable name `length` isn't the greatest of names. I guess it's type is number, but I'm not sure if `.value` on the element returns a number or a string. Sorry about that.

Comment: OK, so your `length` variable is actually of type `string`.  You must first parse it as an `int` to check if its value is greater than 0 using `parseInt()`.

Answer (score 0):

why not:

```
 document.getElementById("length").oninput=function (){
   this.value=Math.max(this.value,1);
 }
```

Or:

```
 document.getElementById("length").oninput=function (){
   this.value=this.value>0?this.value:"";
 }
```

More easy for the user to understand, instead of disabling...

Comment: No, this works technically, but it requires the user to click submit before getting feedback. I have other indicators in the live context to help them along.

Comment: @AnonymousMan no it doesnt. it justs prevents values bigger 1, edited after rereading, it prevents values smaller one now

Comment: I did try it in jsbin before commenting. It allowed me to type a negative number and click submit before alerting me that the value was invalid.

Comment: @AnonymousMan http://jsbin.com/bikegimuqe/edit?js funnily it just doesnt work if added via html elems

Answer (score 0):

`validate()` fires on every keypress, so its better to initialize the `lengthInput` and `submitButton` objects once and use them in the function for better performance.

```js
var lengthInput = document.getElementById("length"),
    submitButton = document.getElementById("submit");

function validate() {
   submitButton.disabled = !(lengthInput.value > 0);  
}

// initial validation
validate();
```

```html
<form name="someform" action="somepage.php" method="post">
    <input name="length" id="length" type="number" min="1" oninput="validate()"/>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modern day browsers require no JavaScript to disable the input.

```css
input:invalid {
  /* background-color: #ffdddd; */
}

form:invalid [type="submit"] {
  opacity: .5;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<form name="someform" action="somepage.php" method="post">
    <input name="length" id="length" type="number" min="1" required/>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

The bug with your code is the fact it is actually `((!length) > 0)`. Changing it to be `!(length>0)` or `(length<=0)` would make more sense. And you are really comparing a string to a number so it should be `Number(length)` so you are not relying on type coercion.